# Naive Bayes with invalid independence assumption

Tags: classification, naive-bayes, independence

I'm trying to understand the effects of adding non-conditionally independent features to a naive Bayes classifier. Let's say I have the features vector $X = [x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]$ and that for each value of $x_3$ I get the same value for $x_4$:

For all $i \in \{samples\}$, $x_{3}^{i} = x_{4}^{i}$

I could say that the conditionally independent assumption of $x_n$ given the class $Y = y_k$ does not hold anymore since the value of $x_{3}^{i}$ foresee $x_{4}^{i}$, and that naive Bayes classifier may not produce the expected results. I'm not really sure about that explanation and I would appreciate your point of view about it.